# Add border to Chart.js tooltips

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible to add a border to ChartJS tooltips and set the color of the border? And if it is possible, how it could be implemented?

Here's my code:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyJuarez/4sgqjtj5/)

HTML:

```
<script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="weeksChart" width="651" height="335"></canvas>
```

JavaScript:

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    draw: function (data) {
        this.scale.startPoint = 25;
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});


var dayTemperatureArray = [-5, 14, 15, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 25, 24, 20, 19, 16];
var nightTemperatureArray = [-10, 4, 5, 6, 8, 11, 12, 15, 17, 15, 13, 12, 11, 9];

var dataWeeks = {
    labels: ["16.02", "17.02", "18.02", "19.02", "20.02", "21.02", "22.02", "23.02", "24.02", "25.02", "26.02", "27.02", "28.02", "01.03"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "Days temperature chart",
        fillColor: "transparent",
        strokeColor: "rgba(244, 6, 6, 1)",
        data: dayTemperatureArray
    }, {
        label: "Nights temperature chart",
        strokeColor: "#3f6bf5",
        data: nightTemperatureArray
    }]
};


var animationComplete = function () {
    var self = this;

    Chart.helpers.each(self.datasets[0].points, function (point, index) {
        Chart.helpers.each(self.datasets, function (dataset) {
            new Chart.Tooltip({
                x: point.x,
                y: dataset.points[index].y,
                xPadding: self.options.tooltipXPadding,
                yPadding: self.options.tooltipYPadding,
                fillColor: self.options.tooltipFillColor,
                textColor: dataset.strokeColor,
                fontFamily: self.options.tooltipFontFamily,
                fontStyle: self.options.tooltipFontStyle,
                fontSize: self.options.tooltipFontSize,
                caretHeight: self.options.tooltipCaretSize,
                cornerRadius: self.options.tooltipCornerRadius,
                cornerRadius: self.options.tooltipCornerRadius,
                text: dataset.points[index].value + '°',
                chart: self.chart,
                custom: self.options.customTooltips
            }).draw()


        });

        self.chart.ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(self.fontSize, self.fontStyle, self.fontFamily)
        self.chart.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        self.chart.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        self.chart.ctx.fillStyle = "#666";
        self.chart.ctx.fillText(point.label, point.x, self.scale.startPoint - 12);
    });
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("weeksChart").getContext("2d");
window.weeksChart = new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(dataWeeks, {
    responsive: true,
    pointDot: true,
    datasetStrokeWidth: 0.5,
    scaleSteps: 2,
    scaleLabel: "<%=value + '°'%>",
    tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>",
    showTooltips: true,
    scaleShowLabels: false,
    scaleFontColor: "transparent",
    onAnimationComplete: function () {
        animationComplete.apply(this)
    },
    tooltipEvents: []
});
```

I've tried different combinations with `tooltipBorderColor`, but obviously it isn't correct way for that thing I try to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the stroke function to draw the border. All the path coordinates are available in the tooltip object.

```
...
var strokeStyle = "red"
self.chart.ctx.lineWidth = 3;
Chart.helpers.each(self.datasets[0].points, function (point, index) {
    Chart.helpers.each(self.datasets, function (dataset) {
        self.chart.ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
        var tooltip = new Chart.Tooltip({
            x: point.x,
            y: dataset.points[index].y,
            xPadding: self.options.tooltipXPadding,
            yPadding: self.options.tooltipYPadding,
            fillColor: self.options.tooltipFillColor,
            textColor: dataset.strokeColor,
            fontFamily: self.options.tooltipFontFamily,
            fontStyle: self.options.tooltipFontStyle,
            fontSize: self.options.tooltipFontSize,
            caretHeight: self.options.tooltipCaretSize,
            cornerRadius: self.options.tooltipCornerRadius,
            cornerRadius: self.options.tooltipCornerRadius,
            text: dataset.points[index].value + '°',
            chart: self.chart,
            custom: self.options.customTooltips
        })
        tooltip.draw()
        self.chart.ctx.stroke();

        var direction = 1;
        if (tooltip.yAlign === "above")
            direction = -1;            

        // erase out the rounded border near where the caret appears
        self.chart.ctx.strokeStyle = self.options.tooltipFillColor;
        self.chart.ctx.beginPath();
        self.chart.ctx.moveTo(tooltip.x - tooltip.caretHeight, tooltip.y + direction * (tooltip.caretPadding + tooltip.caretHeight));
        self.chart.ctx.lineTo(tooltip.x + tooltip.caretHeight, tooltip.y + direction * (tooltip.caretPadding + tooltip.caretHeight));
        self.chart.ctx.stroke();

        // draw the caret angle
        self.chart.ctx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
        self.chart.ctx.beginPath();
        self.chart.ctx.moveTo(tooltip.x + tooltip.caretHeight, tooltip.y + direction * (tooltip.caretPadding + tooltip.caretHeight));
        self.chart.ctx.lineTo(tooltip.x, tooltip.y + direction * tooltip.caretPadding);
        self.chart.ctx.lineTo(tooltip.x - tooltip.caretHeight, tooltip.y + direction * (tooltip.caretPadding + tooltip.caretHeight));
        self.chart.ctx.stroke();
    });
...
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ubwLoern/

---

[image]

Comment: You save me again :) But I have one little question to your solution: when I try to replace all 'ctx' with anything another - everything stop working.. why it  is like that?(((

Comment: oops. those should have been self.chart.ctx. I just updated the answer to correct it. it worked because the context variable towards the end of the fiddle was also coincidentally called ctx!

Comment: still not work if I change every 'ctx' on, for example 'newCtx'... Why it is like that?

Comment: Could you make that change in the fiddle? btw you will be able to only change the last 2 ctx in the fiddle. the ctx in self.chart.ctx is internal to the chart object and you will not / should not change that to newCtx.

Comment: here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnnyJuarez/qm504v5s/2/). But if I will change some 'ctx' to another value, and others leave as they are, this won't call conflicts?? didn't get that part of your answer, sir... sorry :(

Comment: oh, i mean all 'ctx', that in chart object too. I've meant in case of totaly replacement of 'ctx' with something else

Comment: Why do you want to do that - maybe we can figure out how to work around that somehow.

You can't change the ctx in ..chart.ctx to newCtx without changing the Chart.js library code (you usually don't want to do this for this reason :-))

Btw the ..chart.ctx won't interfere with a variable ctx in the same scope if that's what you are looking out for.

Comment: oh!!!! I got it!!!))) thanx a lot:-) everything works fine, but in case if chart's height is a bit smaller (100px for example), than tooltips brake sometimes([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3fg5ha6/1/)). What is possible to do with this?

Comment: Just fixed it and updated answer and fiddle. I saw that condition when I was writing the answer and wrongly assumed it was driven by chart options - didn't realize that small chart height's could trigger it too. Good catch!

Comment: I guess I told You this, but can say one more time: You are The God of ChartJS, sir :)